# Hide on change dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to get a website to process phone numbers and make sure they're validated by country code and area code (to be selected through drop down menus that change based on the previous decision). What I have so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#countryBox").change(function(){
     var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    if(selectedVal == "Canada")
    {
     $("#regionBox.usa,#regionBox.uk,#regionBox.au").hide();
     $("#regionBox.can").show();
    }
    else if(selectedVal == "United States")
    {
     $("#regionBox.can,#regionBox.uk,#regionBox.au").hide();
     $("#regionBox.usa").show();
    }
    else if(selectedVal == "United Kingdom")
    {
     $("#regionBox.usa,#regionBox.au,#regionBox.can").hide();
     $("#regionBox.uk").show();
    } else {
     $("#regionBox.usa,#regionBox.uk,#regionBox.can").hide();
     $("#regionBox.au").show();
    }
  });  
</script>
```

and

```
<form id="registration" action="post">
<label for="username">Username: <input type="textbox" id="username"/></label>
<br />
<label for="password">Password: <input type="textbox" id="password"/></label>
<br />
<label>Country: </label>
    <select id="countryBox">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Country</option>
        <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="United States">United States</option>
        <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    </select>
<br />
<label>Region: </label>
    <select id="regionBox">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Select Region</option>
        <!-- canadian -->
        <option class="can" value="BC">British Columbia</option>
        <option class="can" value="AB">Alberta</option>
        <option class="can" value="SK">Saskatchewan</option>
        <option class="can" value="MB">Manitoba</option>
        <option class="can" value="QC">Quebec</option>
        <option class="can" value="ON">Ontario</option>
        <option class="can" value="NF">Newfoundland</option>
        <option class="can" value="NB">New Brunswick</option>
        <option class="can" value="NS">Nova Scotia</option>
        <option class="can" value="PEI">Prince Edward Island</option>
        <option class="can" value="YK">Yukon Territory</option>
        <option class="can" value="NW">Northwest Territory</option>
        <option class="can" value="NU">Nunavut</option>
        <!-- american -->
        <option class="usa" value="WA">Washington</option>
        <!-- british -->
        <option class="uk" value="LND">London</option>
        <!-- aussie -->
        <option class="au" value="SYD">Sydney</option>
    </select>
<br />

<br />
<label for="phone">Phone Number: <input type="textbox" id="phone"/></label>
<br />
<label for="address">Address: <input type="textbox" id="address"/></label>
<br /><br />
<button form="registration" type="submit" formmethod="post" formaction="SERVER URL HERE" d="submit">Submit</button>
<button form="registration" type="reset" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
```

The other jquery attempts I've made won't change the dropdowns. This one has the dropdowns now (the first step anyways, out of three), but the script doesn't seem to be running/working...

Suggestions on how to get the dropdowns working?

Note that I need to extend the regions for the other countries, and then add the area code selection too... But in order to get that far I need the first bit to work ...

Comment: is your `.can` has a style of `display:none`?

Comment: I can't seem to get the below suggestions to work, like at all. It's almost like the page isn't recognizing the js.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the jQuery selector will look for any element with id regionBox and className set to can, usa, uk, or au. You need to change it to `$('#regionBox option.can');` for canada and likewise with all the others. You could do it like this:

```
$("#countryBox").change(function(){
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();

    $("#regionBox option").hide(); 

    switch(selectedVal) {
        case "Canada":
            $("#regionBox option.can").show();
            break;
        case "United States":
            $("#regionBox option.usa").show();
            break;
        case "United Kingdom":
            $("#regionBox option.uk").show();
            break;
        default:
            $("#regionBox option.au").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$("#countryBox").change(function(){

     var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $("#regionBox option").hide();
    if(selectedVal == "Canada")
    {
     $("#regionBox option.can").show();
    }
    else if(selectedVal == "United States")
    {
     $("#regionBox option.usa").show();
    }
    else if(selectedVal == "United Kingdom")
    {
     $("#regionBox option.uk").show();
    } else {
     $("#regionBox option.au").show();
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the change event is not being bound to the element.  You need to add 
`$( function() {` to your code.  The javascript/jQuery you've added may not fire unless the they are within the DOM ready function (for jQuery bound elements).